How can I add a scrollbar content appearance limit?
It is somewhat peculiar to explain, but it is easy to summarize, it creates a theme content scroll bar, and even adds a button to hide that theme menu, that works very well, but since there are already many themes you can scroll through that theme bar. menus. What happens is that when you scroll a lot the themes are hidden until the beginning of the bottom of that section, or in other words the themes are placed below the hide menu button and it looks bad, I would like them to start hiding before reaching the button, and of course I could adjust that height afterwards, I don't know if anyone knows more about CSS and can help me with that,
This is the Html Code in charge of that section, I leave it for the sake of tags
<div class="interactions">
  <button id="toggle-sidebar">Hide Menu</button>
  <div class="container-bar">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="showContent('topic1')">Definitions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="showContent('tema2')">Some applications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="showContent('topic3')">Activity</a></li>
        <!-- Add more topics here -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="navigation-buttons">
        <button id="prev" onclick="prevContent()">Previous</button>
        <button id="next" onclick="nextContent()">Next</button>
      </div>
      <div id="topic1" class="content">
        <h1>Definitions</h1>
        <p> Information </p>
      </div>
      <div id="topic2" class="content">
        <h1>Some applications</h1>
        <p> Information </p>
      </div>
      <div id="topic3" class="content">
        <h1>Activity</h1>
        <p> Information </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

This is the css in charge of that
.interactions {
  background-color: #72698ccf;
  color: #ffff;
}

.interactions .sidebar {
  margin-top: 180px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #7a748c95;
  padding: 15px;
  boxshadow: 2px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow-y: auto;   /* Adds vertical scrolling */
  height: 650px;      /* Fixed menu height */
  position: absolute; /* Change to absolute so that it does not follow the screen */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s, padding 0.3s;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.interactions .sidebar .content {
  max-height: 600px; /* Maximum height of the content before the scroll bar appears */
  overflow-y: auto;  /* Adds vertical scrolling */
  padding: 5px;      /* Internal space inside the container */
}

.interactions .sidebar ul {
  padding: 85px 0 0 0; /* Adjusts the top padding of the topic list */
  margin-top: 0px;     /* Adjusts the top margin of the topic list */
  list style type: none;
}

.interactions .sidebar ul li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;   /* Adjust the bottom margin between each list element */
}

.interactions .sidebar.collapsed {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.interactions .main-content {
  margin-top: 0px;
  left margin: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  flexible growth: 1;
  transition: left margin 0.3s, max width 0.3s, right padding 0.3s;
  relative position;
  max-width: 1100px;
  right margin: automatic;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;         /* Adds vertical scrolling */
  scrollbar width: none;    /* For Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* For IE 10+ */
}

.interactions .main-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;                      /* Width of the scroll bar */
  background color: transparent; /* Scroll bar background color */
}

.interactions .main-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background color: transparent; /* Color of the "thumb" (the sliding part of the bar) */
}

.interactions .main-content.collapsed {
  left margin: 0;
  max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.interactions .content {
  display: none;
}

.interactions .content.active {
  screen lock;
}

.interactions .navigation-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;    /* Adjust this value as necessary */
  text-align: right;
  transition: right 0.3s;
}


list style type: none; will never work on CSS

We can’t help you until we can run your code and see what it does. However, there are too many syntax errors in your CSS for this to be possible. For example, your code refers to a boxshadow property, but the correct property name is box-shadow. Your declaration relative position; should instead be position: relative;. We can’t help you unless you edit your post to correct these errors.
